# Python multithreaded program does not exit when there is an uncaught exception in one of the threads

Tags: python, multithreading

The code below spawns 100 threads and randomly generates an exception. Even though all the threads are done executing(while some generating exception), the main program still does not exit. Am I doing something wrong? What needs to be modified so that if an exception occurs in one of the threads, the main thread still exits?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from threading import Thread
import sys
import random
from queue import Queue


__author__ = 'aanush'

"""
Testing if threading exits the python script gracefully
"""


class NoException(Exception):
    pass


class ThreadFail(Thread):
    """
    Class which helps us in doing multi-threading which improves performance of the script
    """
    def __init__(self, name, counter, queue_):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue_
        self.threadID = counter
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Expand the tuple from queue and pass it to the target function
            some_random_num = self.queue.get()
            func_test(some_random_num)
            self.queue.task_done()


def func_test(random_num):
    if random_num <= 10:
        print("Sleep time - {} greater than 10. Not raising exception".format(random_num))
    else:
        print('sleep time less than 10 : Raising exception')
        raise NoException


queue = Queue()

for thread_num in range(100):
    worker = ThreadFail('Thread-{}'.format(thread_num), thread_num, queue)
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()

for x in range(1000):
    queue.put(random.randrange(1, 15))
queue.join()
```

Comment: Are you able to Ctrl+c? The resulting stack trace might give you a hint.

Comment: No @progfan, Even Ctrl+c does not do anything. I have to manually kill the process using "kill -9 pid"

Comment: I see. After giving this a second read, I realized I didn't read your question accurately. Specifically, I failed to see the `while True` in your `run()` method. Darkanout's answer is accurate and will help exit gracefully. That being said, it's strange that you are having to `kill` the process and that `ctrl+C` isn't working; ctrl+c works for me against your example.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I am running this multi-threaded program using a bash script in linux and sending an email whenever the script fails(with non-zero exit code). But the process goes in hung state and keeps accumulating day by day with no email (as the script did not exit at all). Now this solution by Darkonaut helps me rectify that.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing a deadlock situation here. A thread which terminates due to an exception, doesn't release held locks on shared resources,
hence the `queue` gets corrupted. You need to catch the exceptions inside the threads and let them exit gracefully.

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        # Expand the tuple from queue and pass it to the target function
        some_random_num = self.queue.get()
        try:
            func_test(some_random_num)
        except NoException:
            pass
        finally:
            self.queue.task_done()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Darkonaut. This looks helpful. I will try this tomorrow and will let you know.!